# Using typeof in JavaScript still causes error for undefined object

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, typeof

Hi i'm querying Amazon API and every now and again an item doesn't have an image. I'm trying to account for this but i still get the error: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
      if (typeof result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage[0].URL[0] !== undefined) {
          //items['image'][i] = result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].LargeImage[0].URL[0];
          console.log(result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage[0].URL[0]);
      }
```

If i comment out the if statement the error disappears - is there a better way to use typeof - which would account for the object property not existing at all? Or can anyone give advise on how to solve?

Thanks

Comment: That's means `results.ItemSearchResponse.Items`, `results.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item`, `results.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage` or `results.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage[0].URL` are `undefined`. Basically, anything you're accessing at some index may be `undefined`. Verify them independently.

Comment: You need to check each level of the Object, `typeof` doesn't handle reference errors within the RHS, `typeof foo; // undefined` but `typeof foo.bar; // error`

Comment: try to log every array to get the one that is undefined
console.log(results.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item)
console.log(results.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage)
console.log(results.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage[0].UR‌​L)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah i just checked and one item was missing a URL. I guess i should add this check to all the returned properties

Answer (score 6):

`typeof` always returns a string, so it's

```
if ( typeof something_to_check !== 'undefined' )
```

If you check for the actual `undefined` it fails, as `undefined !== "undefined"`

As for the error, it means you're trying to access the first index (`[0]`) of something that isn't defined, either

```
result.ItemSearchResponse.Items
```

or

```
result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item
```

or

```
result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage
```

or

```
result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage[0].URL
```

you have to check each one, if you don't know which one fails

```
if ( result.ItemSearchResponse.Items &&
     result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item &&
     result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage &&
     result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage[0].URL
   ) {
     // use 
     var img = result.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage[0].URL[0]
   }
```

If the indices can be wrong, or not an array etc. you have to check for that as well.

Comment: **typeof window.foo.bar** does not (*likely*) return a string

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
var arr = results.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item[i].SmallImage || false;
if(arr[0]){
    // do some work
}
```

Since the condition fails if any of the containing arrays do not exist or if no image exists in `SmallImage`.

Comment: The assignment will throw, so you would probably want to enclose in a **try** block.

Comment: Innovative answer and saves a lot of lines! Thanks a lot!